# How to get TastyPie fields.foreignkey to only return certain fields as apposed to resource uri or full object

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a TastyPie resource setup to return all Quotes from the database.  Each quote has a foreign key relationship to a Django user.

```
class QuoteResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

class Meta:
    queryset = Quote.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    limit = 0
    max_limit = 0
    resource_name = 'quotesreport'
    allowed_methods = ['get']
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    always_return_data = True

def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    return bundle
```

This returns the quote with user set to a resource uri, which is mostly unhelpful to me for what I am trying to accomplish.

I attempted to set full=True on user, but this unfortunately kills response time to an unusable level, and puts too much on the server as there are 4k+ results and growing every day.

Ideally I would like:

```
bundle.data['user'] = "%s %s" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)
```

Is there a way that I have been unable to find to get this seemingly simple task done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with `bundle.data['user'] = "%s %s" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)`?

You could also check out this base class that I wrote. With it you can specify what fields to fetch:

https://github.com/dan-klasson/django-tastypie-specified-fields

Comment: The first problem with that is, in this state, bundle.data['user'] is simply a resource uri.  The second problem, if I add full=True, it proceeds to get the full user object for 4000+ quotes and growing, and the user object itself is quite large as well.  This causes it to take well over 2 minutes, basically rendering it unusable.

Comment: I ended up changing user = fields.IntegerField to get the user pk as apposed to the resource uri.  Now in dehydrate, I am fetching the user object and setting bundle.data['user'] as above.

I had tunnel vision on getting the relation as apposed to just doing it this way.  Thanks!  This cut this particular load time down to approximately 30 seconds as apposed to over 2 minutes.